# Identify and state the running time using Big-O

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, pseudocode

For each of the following algorithms, identify and state the running time using Big-O.

```
//i for (int i = 0; Math.sqrt(i) < n; i++)
cout << i << endl;

//ii for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
cout << i << endl;
int k = n;
    while (k > 0)
    {
        k /= 2;
        cout << k << endl;
    } // while
}

//iii
int k = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    k = k * 2;
for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    cout << j << endl;
```

I've calculate the loop times for the first question using `n=1` and `n=2`. The loop in `i` will run `n^2-1` times. Please help and guide me to identify the Big-O notation.

Comment: By the way, note that Big-O generally uses only the term with the highest degree from the polynomial expressing the time or space complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(i) for (int i = 0; Math.sqrt(i) < n; i++)
cout << i << endl;
```

The loop will run until squareRoot(i) < N , or until i < N^2. Thus the running time will be `O(N^2)`, ie. `quadratic`.

```
(ii) for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
        int k = n;
        while (k > 0)
        {
            k /= 2;
            cout << k << endl;
        } // while
      }
```

The outer loop will run for N iterations. The inner loop will run for logN iterations(because the inner loop will run for k=N, N/2, N/(2^2), N/(2^3), ...logN times). Thus the running time will be `O(N logN)`, ie. `linearithmic`.

```
(iii)
int k = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    k = k * 2;
for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    cout << j << endl;
```

The value of k after the execution of the first loop will be 2^n as k is multiplied by 2 n times. The second loop runs k times. Thus it will run for 2^n iterations. Running time is `O(2^N)`, ie. `exponential`.

Answer (score 1):

- For the first question, you will have to loop until `Math.sqrt(i) >= n`, that means that you will stop when `i >= n*n`, thus the first program runs in `O(n^2)`.
- For the second question, the outer loop will execute `n` times, and the inner loop keeps repeatedly halving `k` (which is initially equal to `n`). So the inner loop executes `log n` times, thus the total time complexity is `O(n log n)`.
- For the third question, the first loop executes `n` times, and on each iteration you double the value of `k` which is initially `1`. After the loop terminates, you will have `k = 2^n`, and the second loop executes `k` times, so the total complexity will be `O(2^n)`

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma Notation, you can formally obtain the following results:

```
(i)
```

[image]

[image]

```
(ii)
```

[image]

```
(iii)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple hints may allow you to solve most of running time complexity problems in CS tests/homeworks.

- If something decrease by a factor of 2 on each iteration, that's a `log(N)`.  In your second case the inner loop index is halved each time.
- Geometric series, 
  `a r^0 + a r^1 + a r^2 ... = a (r^n - 1) / (r - 1)`.

  Write out third problem: 
  `2 + 4 + 8 + 16 ... = 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + ...`
  and use the closed form formula.

Generally it helps to look for `log2` and to write few terms to see if there is a repeatable pattern.

Other common questions require you to know factorials and its approximation (Sterling's approximation)